# How to handle done button in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to add `UIWebView` in my `UIViewController` like this.

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'320', height:'568', videoId:'%@', events: { 'onLoad': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";

NSString *strYoutubeId = [arrSearchAssignmentList[indexPath.row][@"id"][@"$t"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" withString:@""];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, strYoutubeId];

videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoView.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
videoView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Here I want to hide `UIWebView` when done button clicked.

So is there anyway to hide the `UIWebView` when the done button is clicked or how can I handle the done button in the `UIWebView when it plays a video in full screen?

Comment: What done button are you talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about Done button outside webview. And On click of Done Button Hide Webview?

Comment: I am talking about when we play any video in UIWEBVIEW in FullScreen at that time in upper left side it shows done button.

Answer (score 0):

When you click DONE button it will stop playing video.If you are working on NAtive app then there will be only one Webview.

Or if you are working on Hybrid app. Then there will be two Webviews. One on which you run your app and one on which you can play video.

Outside Webview show Close button on click of which you can hide the Webview.